# jmeter ultimate thread group use same user on each iteration

Tags: jmeter, load

I'm looking at doing spike tests and I think ultimate thread groups in Jmeter are the way, but I need Jmeter to keep the connections open during the test and use same user on each iteration like it does in regular thread groups, is there a way to force that in Ultimate thread groups as well?

If not, is there a way to do spike testing with regular thread groups in Jmeter?

I've tried setting the thread schedule to produce spikes in ultimate thread group but Jmeter continues to generate new connections per each request. In regular thread groups this can be solved by checking "Use same user on each iteration" but that check box is not present in Ultimate Thread Groups.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of the following options:

1. Don't use Ultimate Thread Group, the "spike" can be implemented using normal [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in combination with [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
2. If you want to proceed with the Ultimate Thread Group you can add a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to it and set the desired number of iterations there

More information: [Stress Testing, Soak Testing and Spike Testing Best Practices with BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/stress-testing-vs-soak-testing-vs-spike-testing)